# Symfony2 getID on not a object

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

how i modified mysql and changed some values

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /var/www/junior/src/Pit/JuniorBundle/Entity/LeadRepository.php on line 92

I modified mysql table by phpmyadmin changed some values, and now i have the problem that i dont know where i made the mistake. How can i find out , which object the reference is missing? how can i determine that?  Mysql helps us there.

Best regards,

Andreas

Comment: post contents of LeadRepository.php please

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wxCug2K2

Comment: what is $property->getProperty() doing?

Comment: Can you paste code from Lead entity?

Comment: what did you change in the database?